# deleting computer account from AD c#

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm trying to delete a computer account from AD using this code:

```
string ldapBase = "ldap://x.y.z.com/";
string sFromWhere = ldapBase + "rootDSE";
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
string defaultNamingContext = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();

/* Retrieving the computer to remove */
sFromWhere = ldapBase + defaultNamingContext;
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(&(cn=waprptest))"; // MACHSUPR is the computer to delete
dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

SearchResultCollection srcComputer = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();

// Deleting computer 
foreach (SearchResult aComputer in srcComputer)
{
  DirectoryEntry computerToDel = aComputer.GetDirectoryEntry();
  computerToDel.DeleteTree();
  computerToDel.CommitChanges();
}
```

I'm getting exception @

```
string defaultNamingContext = root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0].ToString();
```

as the `rot.Properties` count is 0

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong... I'm a newbie to AD

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, to get the `RootDSE` folder, you must use this LDAP string:

```
LDAP://RootDSE
```

First of all, the `LDAP` **must be** in all capital letters, and `RootDSE` also has a capital `R` at its beginning. LDAP strings **are** case sensitive!

Also: if you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching (much simpler than using `DirectorySearcher`!):

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a ComputerPrincipal 
   ComputerPrincipal qbeComputer = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeComputer);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal"
       ComputerPrincipal cp = found as ComputerPrincipal;

       if (cp != null)
       {
           // do something with the computer account 
       }
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Comment: you mean whole ldapBase string should be in capital letters or only ldap in ldapBase  string should be in capitals???

Comment: @shiv455: the `LDAP://` prefix **must be** all capitalized - and `RootDSE` must have a capital `R` at the beginning$

Comment: Thats perfect i got rid off exception...can you please lemme know how can i get all the computernames in the context...and what are these defaultNamingContext,cn,distinguishedName properties for...please dont mind as im newbie to this..any reference or your explanation would be really helpful..

Comment: can i fetch the computername irrespective of domain??cos as of now i need to configure the domianname which needs to be passed to PrincipalContext